# Calling elasticsearch via curl in php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have some problems getting data from elasticsearch. I have tested the following simple php script (no framework necessary):

```
<?php
$url = "curl -XGET http://<myelasticurl>:80/_cat/indices";
$username = "testUser";
$password = "secret";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
?>
```

The only response I get is: `"bool(false)"`

Comment: Take another look at your `$url`.

Comment: What's wrong with my url?

Comment: It has `curl -XGET ` stuck to the front.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Thanks! Now it works but is there a way to get the response as json?

Comment: Doesn't Elasticsearch *always* return JSON?

Comment: It seems not. The result looks good but the content-type is "text/plain; charset=UTF-8".

Comment: Is that a problem for you? If so, why?

Comment: The script should be a kind of interface. I want to get the data and transfer it to another application. That third-party-app needs then the input in json format.

Comment: You said the result "looks good," so I assume it's already JSON. If so, why do you care what the `Content-Type` header says?

Comment: Oh, the `/_cat` APIs are specifically *not* JSON: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html. On that page, it says `?format=json` will do the trick, or `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: Great, that was the trick!